# WSL Keeps crashing when using VSCode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using a blanco Ubuntu WSL installation from Windows Store, running VSCode from there with repository in the `/home` folder. No WSL extensions installed.

It is working for some time, but eventually always leads to WSL crashing. VSCode cannot connect, because I can also not connect anymore to the WSL installation by terminal.

[image]

Then I end up using `wsl --shutdown` in `cmd` and restarting Docker to make it work again for some time. But it keeps coming back.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that WSL is running out of memory.

Either extend the memory to WSL in `.wslconfig` or figure out ways to limit memory usage.

In my case I quit using Docker and ran the application without it.

Comment: Documentation on how to edit `.wslconfig`: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config